Questions about mma instruction with Nvidia ptx
Hi my understanding about mma instruction with ptx is (please tell me if I'm wrong):

it is a per warp instruction
it need to load specific element into register of each thread within the target warp
The size of the multiplication is fixed (a limited set to choose from)

I have a compiled ptx instruction set and I picked out one mma instruction:
//
// Generated by LLVM NVPTX Back-End
//

.version 8.4
.target sm_89
.address_size 64

    // .globl   matmul_kernel
.extern .shared .align 16 .b8 global_smem[];

.visible .entry matmul_kernel(
    .param .u64 matmul_kernel_param_0,
    .param .u64 matmul_kernel_param_1,
    .param .u64 matmul_kernel_param_2,
    .param .u32 matmul_kernel_param_3,
    .param .u32 matmul_kernel_param_4,
    .param .u32 matmul_kernel_param_5,
    .param .u32 matmul_kernel_param_6,
    .param .u32 matmul_kernel_param_7,
    .param .u32 matmul_kernel_param_8
)
.maxntid 128, 1, 1
{
    ...
    ldmatrix.sync.aligned.m8n8.x4.shared.b16 { %r3100, %r3101, %r3102, %r3103 }, [ %r561 + 0 ];
    ...
    ldmatrix.sync.aligned.m8n8.x4.trans.shared.b16 { %r3084, %r3085, %r3086, %r3087 }, [ %r581 + 0 ];
    ...
    mov.f32     %f2306, 0f00000000;
    mov.b32     %r3107, 2;
    mov.b32     %r3106, 0;
    shl.b32     %r2885, %r100, 1;
    shl.b32     %r2894, %r101, 1;
    shl.b32     %r2895, %r102, 1;
    shl.b32     %r2896, %r103, 1;
    shl.b32     %r2897, %r104, 1;
    shl.b32     %r2898, %r105, 1;
    shl.b32     %r2899, %r106, 1;
    mov.u32     %r3104, %r765;
    mov.u32     %r3105, %r758;
    mov.f32     %f2307, %f2306;
    mov.f32     %f2308, %f2306;
    mov.f32     %f2309, %f2306;
    ...
    mma.sync.aligned.m16n8k16.row.col.f32.f16.f16.f32 { %f2306, %f2307, %f2308, %f2309 }, { %r3100, %r3101, %r3102, %r3103 }, { %r3084, %r3085 }, { %f2306, %f2307, %f2308, %f2309 };
}

Now my questions are:

by instruction, it is a D{16, 8}=A{16, 16}B{16, 8}+D{16, 8}$ multiplication with A,B in f16 type and D in f32 type. But the actual load instruction only load 4 regs for A. Does it mean that for each thread in warp, it will only load 8 element (since register is 32 bit width) and the total 32 thread will load 8x32=16x16 element of A? and same for matrix B and the result matrix D (D is 4x32=16x8 in type f32)
does the tag sync means the target warp will continue until the tensor core finish matrix mult?
it can be seen that the ptx version is 8.4, and from official doc it shows that 8.4 only support the shape of m16n8k64 for sparse and .m16n8k32 for dense, there is no support for m16n8k16, or m16n8k64 means it support any shape that m<16 and n<8 and k<64?
as mentioned above, what is the meaning of dense and sparse of matrix?



Yes, for operands which are 32-bits wide (e.g. f32 operands, such as C,D) each register holds one operand.  For operands which are 16-bits wide (e.g. f16 operands such as A,B) each register holds two operands.  For both C and D for this instruction, we need 16x8 = 128 operands total, and these are distributed four per thread in the warp (4x32 = 128).  For A, we need 16x16 (= 256) operands, and these are distributed 8 per thread in the warp (8x32 = 256).  However since these f16 operands are stored two per 32-bit register, we only need 128 registers warp-wide, which is four registers per thread, just like C and D.  For B, we need 16x8 16 bit operands, and this works out to two 32-bit registers per thread in the warp.

The sync tag means that in a previous warp-divergent situation, this instruction will wait until all threads in the warp reach the point of the instruction, before dispatching the instruction to the tensorcore unit.  If we imagined a non-sync variant of the instruction (it does not exist, it is just for illustration) then it would be as if we executed a __syncwarp() followed by the non-sync variant of the instruction.

No, the indicated instructions support matrix multiplication of exactly the sizes listed; not more, not less.  For example, a m16n8k16 instruction requires exactly M=16, not M<16.  This is true whether we are talking about dense or sparse variants.

The terminology here dense vs. sparse is similar to the usage in linear algebra.  A dense matrix tensorcore calculation means that all matrix values are assumed to be possibly non-zero, and therefore a "full calculation" will be done.  A sparse matrix tensorcore calculation means that some of the input matrix values are (i.e. are assumed to be) zero.  The benefit of the sparse matrix calculation is that it will assume these values are zero, and will therefore somehow optimize its use of calculation hardware to deliver higher throughput.  The exact definition of which input matrix values are assumed to be zero requires specification that is covered in the PTX manual.



thanks for your answer, but for point 3 as you said according to the ptx document the version of 8.4 would only support he shape of m16n8k64 for sparse and m16n8k32 for dense. Then how can the compiler resulted in m16n8k16?

Dense m16n8k16 for f16 has been supported since PTX version 7.0, see here.

This is the entry in that table that shows support: `mma
Dense
Floating-point - .f16
.m8n8k4
PTX ISA version 6.4
.m16n8k8
PTX ISA version 6.5
.m16n8k16
PTX ISA version 7.0`

so the table showed is the new introduced shape right? which mean the later version can use all shapes introduced in previous ones???

Yes, if you have PTX version 7.0 or newer, than you can issue the shapes .m8n8k4, .m16n8k8 and .m16n8k16, for that particular variant (mma, f16, Dense).  If you had PTX 6.5 or higher, but less than 7.0, you could only issue the shapes .m8n8k4 and .m16n8k8.  If you had PTX 6.4 you could only issue .m8n8k4.  If you had PTX 6.3 or lower, you could not issue any of those.
